# why GPIO does not work when executed from python shell but works from script

Tags: rpi.gpio, python-3, pi-gpio

When I run this python script `led.py` it works.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(24,GPIO.OUT)
print("LED on")
GPIO.output(24,GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(1)
print("LED off")
GPIO.output(24,GPIO.LOW)
```

but if I open python3 shell and paste the above code

```
script# python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jan 22 2021, 20:04:44) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
>>> import time
>>> GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
>>> GPIO.setwarnings(False)
>>> GPIO.setup(24,GPIO.OUT)
>>> print("LED on")
LED on
```

then it does not work. what is happening here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting the GPIO level.

The LED will go on when you execute

```
GPIO.output(24,GPIO.HIGH)
```

The LED will go off when you execute

```
GPIO.output(24,GPIO.LOW)
```

Comment: daaah how did I missed it